# Secret Sharing & Information Theory

Tags: information-theory

I'm reading a paper -- [Common Randomness in Information Theory and Cryptograph-secret](https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/download/1780491/2312929/Ahlswede_79.pdf).

And I do have trouble in understanding formula (2.6):

$$
\frac {1}{n} H(K)> H-\epsilon \tag{2.6}\label{2.6},
$$

with  $\epsilon>0$ some arbitrary number larger than the probability that two $K$ and $L$ aren't the same and $H$ being called an *achievable key rate*. $n$ is the length of the product source word, and the statement is that there's an $n$ large enough that this inequality holds.

For 2.4, 2.5 and 2.7, there are explanation in the paper. But the author mentioned nothing about 2.6. As far as I concerned, $H(K)/n$ is like an upper bound of $H$. I'm not sure if $H(K)/n$ is the so called key-capacity. And $H$(achievable rate) should always less than key capacity.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! It's not quite clear what your problem with $\eqref{2.6}$ is, could you elaborate?

Comment: To make that easier I copied the formula to your question and added the definition of the symbols.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Could you explain what specifically is surprising to you here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller For 2.4, 2.5 and 2.7, there are explanation in the paper. But the author mentioned nothing about 2.6. As far as I concerned, H(k)/n is like an upper bound of H. I'm not sure if H(k)/n is the so called key-capacity. And H(achievable rate) should always less than key capacity.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include this, please? Then it would stand on its own as question :)